# Pass ID to Modal form box on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read a bunch of SO posts on how to do this but I am unable to get it to work with my script.  Maybe someone smarter than me can see what Im missing here.
I am trying to pass the ID to the modal box. The user will then input notes and it will update in the DB.

```
echo "<td>" . $Agent_ID. "<br><a href='' class='btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4' data-note-id='". $id . "' data-toggle='modal' id='" . $id . "' data-target='#notes'>Add Notes</a></td>";
```

My Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="notes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Notes</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form method="post">
      <div class="modal-body mx-3">
        <div class="md-form mb-5">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>

          <textarea name="note" value="" placeholder="Type Your Note Here" id="defaultForm-email" class="form-control validate"></textarea>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS

```
<script>

$('#notes').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var note = $(e.relatedTarget).data('note-id');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="note"]').val(note);
});

</script>
```

I tried this as well as you can see its very similar
http://jsfiddle.net/k7FC2/

Comment: do you have multiple modals with the same code or multiple callers for the same modal?

Comment: you are making complex dom selectors for no reason. always try to do `$("#id")` but id should be unique in your DOM. It's faster and cleaner.

Comment: Its only one modal.

Comment: @csandreas1 Im not sure what you mean with that.  Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: When will your modal be opened? When click on the link?

Comment: I am assuming php for the first chunk of code. I would double check the generated source and see if $id is populated correctly.

Comment: @csandreas1 Yes it is.  When link is clicked it opens the modal box.  But no ID information is posted inside the textbox.  I have checked my code and everyting works fine as well as displaying the ID number.

Answer (score 1):

Your input box selector is wrong. You changed the `<input name="note">` to `<textbox name="note">`. Update your selector to match. Change `input[name="note"]` to `textarea[name="note"]`.

Comment: I tried to build you a new jsFiddle with working code but its hanging on save.

Comment: I tried this but didnt seem to work.  Ill try to figure this out lol

Comment: Would it matter which jquery library i am using?
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

Comment: https://codepen.io/ellucidone/pen/wvaMZyz This works on this page but on my server it does not work at all

Comment: do you get any errors in your javascript console? any resources not loading? which part isnt working on your server? the modal or pushing a value into the text box?

Comment: The modal is working but nothing passed to it. No errors either in my js

Comment: Actually now i am getting [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 63ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 74ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 69ms

Comment: While the modal is displayed in the console, if you run $('textarea[name="note"]').val("some test text"), does it push text into the box?

Comment: you should also verify that note is getting the correct value, try putting a console.log(note) after the var note = ... assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var thisID
$('a').click(e=>{
  thisID = e.currentTarget.id
   console.log(thisID)
})
```

Now, you can use the id variable anywhere in your code (`thisID`)